# Android google map Marker won't Show

Tags: android, google-maps, gson, okhttp

I'm new at android development. I'm trying to add a Google marker at my App map but it won't show. I can set a Marker if the Marker's lat & lng is a double number,but when i put the API data in it it won't show.Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    getLocation();

    // This marker will show at my app screen !
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(24.9992666, 121.5082287);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
            .title("This is office Marker")
    );
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));





    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    this.googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);




    HttpUtil.sendHttpRequest("http://113.10.198.159/appapi/getWIFIList", new HttpCallbackListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish(String response) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonBean jsonBean = gson.fromJson(response, JsonBean.class);

            Log.d(TAG, "【】【id】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getId());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【merchant_id】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getMerchant_id());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【merchant_name】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getMerchant_name());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【city】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getCity());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【area】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getArea());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【address】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getAddress());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【lat】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getLat());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【lng】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getLng());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【addTime】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getAddTime());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【dlat】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getDlat());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【dlng】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getDlng());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【wificode】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getWificode());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【upstream】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getUpstream());
            Log.d(TAG, "【】【downstream】【】" + jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getDownstream());

            //// This marker can not show at my app screen
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getDlat(), jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getDlng());
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                    .title("This is Test Marker")
            );

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {

        }
    });
}



public class HttpUtil {
public static void sendHttpRequest(final String address, final HttpCallbackListener listener) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                String s1 = "lat";
                String s2 = "24.9992666";
                String s3 = "lng";
                String s4 = "121.5082287";
                RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add(s1, s2)
                        .add(s3, s4)
                        .build();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(address)
                        .post(requestBody)  //post
                        .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                String responseData = response.body().string();
                if (listener != null) {
                    // onFinish() method
                    listener.onFinish(responseData);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    // onError() method
                    listener.onError(e);
                }

            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

Comment: code please. Thanks you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please add code to get idea what are you tried?

Comment: @SouravGanguly Here are my code, this is the first question when i'm using Stackoverflow,sorry about that,i'm a new guy.

Comment: @IshanFernando Sorry ! I just put my code in it!

Comment: What the response coming? Can you make sure you have different lat lng then one mentioned in onMapReady?

Comment: @SouravGanguly I have update the code already, the response is in the onFinish() method. Yeah there are many lat & lng when the data i post by the API links. the getResult().get(0) is the first data, the 0 is index, i will change later.

Comment: Thanks everyone，i fix it used Handler, just put the Gson and Marker code in it. I think the reason is the data use in the UI(Google Map Show).

Answer (score 0):

Is the map shoiwing up? What is inside your 
     getLocation();
function, if there is not something like the following, then add it

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Also remember to zoom in and out and pan the map around, may be the marker is plotted where you did not expect it to be.
if it still does not work, follow this tutorial, it must work.
[google maps with marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker)

Comment: Yeah the map also showing up. I can see the first  Marker on my map screen, but the second one can not show. That's really kill me.

Comment: can you post your whole mainActivity.java code, and what are the results received from http://113.10.198.159/appapi/getWIFIList, when I tried it I got almost nothing, make sure it receives proper coordinates parse them to double before trying to plot them on map, if still does not work, check LOGCAT logs carefully and take a look at this link https://gist.github.com/saxman/5347195

Comment: Thank you! But i fix it already, i put the problem code in the Handler and it work already! Any way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting the right value from the json? It may be returning a string. You might want to try converting it to the `valueOf` to get the desired type.

For a double it would be something like:

```
double lat = Double.valueOf(jsonBean.getResult().get(0).getDlat());
```

Comment: Yes the data type is true, i use postman check is. The second Marker's lat&lng all  have value when i debug app, but it still can not show in the screen. Also the Android Studio show the app's debug prombles about Handler.